# Error when adding the consumer application. An application with the same name already exists

Tags: oauth-2.0, openid, wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 Identity Server version 5.0.

I’m following this tutorial: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/Configuring+Inbound+Authentication+for+a+Service+Provider#ConfiguringInboundAuthenticationforaServiceProvider-ConfiguringOAuth/OpenIDConnect

But every time I try to add an application in the “OAuth/OpenID Connect Configuration” under “Inboud Authentication Configuration” during the SP configuration, WSO2 gives me this error:
“Error when adding the consumer application. An application with the same name already exists.”

I really doesn’t understand which application refers because this is my first configuration on a fresh installation of WSO2 IS.

Let me know if I can attach more info/file to help finding the solution

Comment: can you post the steps to reproduce this error?

Comment: Add a new service provider and then follow the same steps in the tutorial that i've linked in the OP, the section "Configuring OAuth/OpenID Connect" ;)

Comment: Could you please send the error logs in backend console. Basically exception that you find in the wso2carbon.log file?

Comment: How did you solve?